# Xeditable Date input configuration to accept dates before 1970

Tags: javascript, x-editable

Using x-editable JS plugin I added a new date type input in my form (Combodate (date) element), everything looks fine, but the input accepts the only date starting from 1/1/1970. I need to change this configuration because the birthdate of my customer can be previous than 1970.

Unfortunately in the x-editable documentation ([link](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html)) there isn't any configuration related to the date range.

Below my HTML code (with PHP data):

```
<a href="#" id="dipendente-datanascita" 
    data-type="combodate" 
    data-value="<?php echo $dipendente["datanascita"]; ?>" 
    data-format="YYYY-MM-DD" 
    data-viewformat="DD/MM/YYYY" 
    data-template="DD/MM/YYYY" 
    data-pk="1" 
    data-title="Select Date of birth" 
    data-url="api/update-dipendente.php?id=<?php echo $id_dipendente; ?>"
    class="editable editable-click" style="">
    <?php echo $utility->formatDate($dipendente["datanascita"]); ?>
</a>
```

and the JS part:

```
$('#dipendente-datanascita').editable({
    prepend: "Non selezionato",
    mode: 'inline',
    inputclass: 'form-control-sm'
});
```

Can anyone help with this? thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide working example? As their datepicker example allows to select it: https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html?c=popup#vacation

Comment: Please note, that Unix timestamp `0` is equals to `1970/01/01 00:00:00`

Comment: in the example there 2 different date inputs, I'm referring to Combodate (date) and not to the date picker.

Comment: Hi @Justinas, I know, but it is a combodate and I'm saving it in a SQL element type date that accepts dates before 1970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year 1970 is a configuration that can be edit changing the file bootstrap-editable.js that is part of the library (remember to also generate the minified js if the app uses it). Here an example of the configuration:

```
$.fn.combodate.defaults = {
     //in this format value stored in original input
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm',      
    //in this format items in dropdowns are displayed
    template: 'D / MMM / YYYY   H : mm',
    //initial value, can be `new Date()`    
    value: null,                       
    minYear: 1970,
    maxYear: 2015,
    yearDescending: true,
    minuteStep: 5,
    secondStep: 1,
    firstItem: 'empty', //'name', 'empty', 'none'
    errorClass: null,
    roundTime: true, // whether to round minutes and seconds if step > 1
    smartDays: false // whether days in combo depend on selected month: 31, 30, 28
};
```

Change the minYear value and it will work!!